# Уменьшить количество запросов к БД

Tags: php, ооп

Хочу узнать Ваше мнение по такому вопросу:

На сайте существует страница с новостями, под каждой новостью возможно оставить комментарий.
Для обеих сущностей (комментарии, новости) написаны свои классы.

**Задача состоит в следующем:**

После написания и подтверждения отправки комментария необходимо уведомить в режиме реалтайм того пользователя, от имени которого написана новость. Этот механизм сделан, но имеет один недочет.

При отправлении уведомления посылается информация о пользователе, который оставил комментарии и информация о новости. Таким образом, в системе выполняется два раза одинаковый запрос, один для вытаскивания информации о новости при ее просмотре, второй, при отправки уведомления, с выборкой по ID.

Еще раз хочу заметить, что для каждой сущности написаны отдельные классы, так же для уведомлений.
Какие есть механизмы решения задачи в ООП?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я, если честно, не понял схемы (где именно информация вытаскивается два раза)(и опасности повторения простого селекта), но в любом случае ООП к вытаскиванию данных и их передаче не имеет никакого отношения.

По-хорошему у вас просто должна быть некая черная дыра, куда сбрасывается либо уведомление целиком, либо айдишник, по которому можно восстановить уведомление (в этом случае ситуация будет повторяться, но, опять же, не вижу в этом ничего страшного).